# message sent to deallocated instance 0x141dafb0 iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i am getting this error "message sent to deallocated instance 0x141dafb0" its comming from a UIBarButtonItem when its beeing pressed on the application. any help would be greatly appreciated

Error:

```
 *** -[PeerConnection performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x14143ff0
```

PeerConnection.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>

@interface PeerConnection : NSObject <GKPeerPickerControllerDelegate, GKSessionDelegate> {
 UIBarButtonItem *StartConnection;
}

- (IBAction) StartConnectionAction;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *StartConnection;

@end
```

PeerConnection.m

```
    #import "PeerConnection.h"


@implementation PeerConnection
@synthesize StartConnection;


- (IBAction) StartConnectionAction {
 NSLog(@"Start Connection to the other IPhones");
 [StartConnection release];
}

- (void)dealloc {
 [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

i have enabled Zombie and that is all its giving to me

Answer (score 2):

Don't release your `StartConnection` button until `-dealloc`. Releasing that bar button item in `-StartConnectionAction` is your problem--anything the UI tries to do with it after that will call a zombie.

Comment: i did that before but it was still giving off the same error but with a different exception code now its giving me " *** -[PeerConnection performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x14159ff0"

Comment: That's happening somewhere outside the code you've provided us. Make darn sure you're not releasing anything before the viewController that's going to use it deallocs.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you have released the StartConnection object. Now, when the automatic dealloc is called, the reference was not found (as already removed) and hence you got the error.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to access of the instance that is already removed during GC. The error occurs in a case when you use autorelease.

```
ThePlannerAppDelegate *delg = [(ThePlannerAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] autorelease];
```

Now this is most likely the GC will destroy the reference although delg points to the main window delegate.

My point is use autorelease safely.

Important: The error will occur when a message will be sent to an dead reference.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, but was using a singleton with autorelease on shared method, took off autorelease from there and added on it's dealloc  , and all works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Old Thread; But thought I might add.

If your app isn't using ARC; Use The Analyse Feature to find all the problems that may arise due to releasing/retaining objects.

Shortcut is `command + shift + B`

Totally useful !